# Bitlocker boot loop

Tags: windows-8.1, bitlocker

I run into a bitlocker boot loop by my Asus T100. I can unlock it with the key from my ms account, but it still asks for the key by every boot. This behavior started 1-2 months ago. Any idea how to stop it?

Integrity tells me everything is fine with Windows files. I had some video artifacts with it recently. Some black dots appeared in Firefox and these dots moved when I scrolled. I restarted it and everything works fine. I am suspecting some kind of hardware issues, but I am not sure.

I would have installed Linux on it a long time ago, but half of the features are not supported and wifi is not stable according to the wiki. :S https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices/t100ta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a hardware called [Trusted Platform Module (TPM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_Platform_Module) on the main board of the tablet. I am not sure whether it is part of the CPU or the mobo (most probably the CPU), but it does not really matter, because as far as I know we are talking about a [SoC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_on_a_chip) here, so the Intel Atom CPU is soldered to the main board. In theory this TPM is storing the bitlocker key, so I don't need to type that key by booting the system up. According to the event logs this TPM is malfunctioning, so it cannot deliver the key, and that's why I need to type it manually. The video artifacts are probably caused by a video card error, and since the video card is integrated to the CPU too, I think these are clear signs of a dying CPU.

I contacted with a local Asus service, but replacing the main board without warranty would cost 200 EUR, which is close to the price of a new tablet, so that is not the solution I was hoping for. I can order a cheaper main board from Amazon or Ebay for 50 EUR with a somewhat weaker CPU and replace it myself. I have a T100TA, but in theory every T100* board is compatible with every T100* device. So I think I'll order a main board and we'll see whether it solves these issues. My only problem will be opsystem install, since I guess it will be harder than usual by these tablets. Before continuing I'll try out Linux with these dying board. I am just curious how it runs on it.